# Advanced Custom Fields (Loop user profile field)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a field within the wordpress profile (created with a plugin called Advanced Custom Fields) which allows customers to upload their logo. I would like to now loop through all those customers and display that logo (in a list preferably)

Here are some attempts, can someone guide me to the right direction:

```
<?php
    $args = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'display_name' ) ) );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<img src="';
            the_field('company_logo');
            echo '" alt="';
            the_field('company_name');
            echo '"/>';
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;
```

Here is another attempt

```
        <?php
            $blogusers = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'display_name' ) ) );

            $variable = get_field('company_logo', $blogusers);

            foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
                echo the_field('company_logo', $blodusers);
            }

        ?>
```

Another

```
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users('orderby=company_name');
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
    $image1 = get_field('company_logo', 'user_'. $author_id );
        $image2 = get_field('company_name', 'user_'. $author_id );

    foreach ($blogusers as $author_id) {
            echo '<li><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="profile1" src="';
            echo $image1['url'];
            echo '"/></div><img class="profile2 hoverShow" src="';
            echo $image2['url'];
            echo '"/><div class="imageOverlay"><p>';
            echo '</p></div></li>';

    }
?>
```

None of the above are showing any results apart from the HTML echos'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `get_field` *for each user* within your loop.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users();

    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {

            $author_id = $user->ID;

            $image1 = get_field('company_logo', 'user_'. $author_id );
            $image2 = get_field('company_name', 'user_'. $author_id );

            echo '<li><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="profile1" src="';
            echo $image1['url'];
            echo '"/></div><img class="profile2 hoverShow" src="';
            echo $image2['url'];
            echo '"/><div class="imageOverlay"><p>';
            echo '</p></div></li>';

    }
?>
```

Note: i'm not sure what the data is actually like for your `company_logo` and `company_name` fields.. sounds kinda weird that `company_name` should return an image..

**Edit:** If you want to sort by company_name, you'll need to do something like this (Note this isn't tested)

```
$blogusers = get_users(array( 'meta_key' => 'company_name', 'orderby'=>'meta_value' ));
```

Check the doc for more details http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query